# How to install libssl.so.10 and libcrypto.so.10 64 for centos?

Tags: php, apache, centos

```
Error: Package: php54-cli-5.4.26-1.ius.el6.x86_64 (ius)
           Requires: libcrypto.so.10(OPENSSL_1.0.1)(64bit)
Error: Package: php54-5.4.26-1.ius.el6.x86_64 (ius)
           Requires: libssl.so.10(libssl.so.10)(64bit)
```

I have an issue I can't update from php 5.3 to php 5.4, because of this dependencies, how or where can I find those `libssl.so.10` and `libcrypto.so.10` 64 bit?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Does your version of yum have a 'provides' option?

If it does, then 'yum provides */filename' might work if one of your repo filelists_db has it.

Comment: I've tried yum provides */libssl, matches not found, where can I get that libssl 64 bit?